# Change ProgressIndicator color

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I want to change the color of the dots of the `SystemTray.ProgressIndicator` to fit my app's overall design. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks for any advice.

BTW: [Binding to ProgressIndicator in XAML](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/246355/Binding-the-WP7-ProgressIndicator-in-XAML)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can, they appear to be tied to whatever color the carrier/handset maker combination decided to use.

So for example I have three WP7 devices, two on Verizon (both HTC Trophy) and and one on AT&T (Samsung Focus). The metro tiles on the Verizon phones are red, I'm guessing to match the red Verizon logo, and so the dots are red. The AT&T phone's tiles are blue, I'm guessing to match the blue AT&T logo, and so the dots are blue.

Comment: Of course, it's the accent color by default... (can be changed in settings). I need to change it to my application's color... But I've accepted that I can't change it :-)